# How to count all hashtags in a given set of tweets, using map reduce?

Tags: hadoop, twitter, mapreduce

I want to have a counter to check the most popular hashtags. 
Now the problem is that each tweet can have multiple hashtags, In this case how do i set the hashtag as the key? because in every iteration i have an array of hashtags from each tweet.

How do i break this problem to fit the map-reduce paradigm?

Answer (score 1):

You can do multiple call to write / collect in a single map call.

Search all your HasTags in your tweet and iterate on them, calling write / collect each time